# How to delete a message from WhatsApp Group Chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, delete

I'm a member of one group of our college friends in WhatsApp. There is one specific message that I want to remove. I know if I try to delete it, it will only be deleted from my phone, but I want to know is there any way that I can permanently delete it. I don't want anybody in the group to see that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to delete a message before it reaches the recipient is to delete it before it reaches the server.

> > Turn off the data connection and delete the message while it still has the clock icon beside it.

If the message is submitted to server, people in group will be able to see the message.